# JWT token exception error handling when decoding in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt

When I add a character to my token, an exception error occurs. If the token is invalid, I want the program to give an invalid message.

```
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

    public UserPolicy(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this._contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserPolicyRequirement requirement)
    {
        var request = _contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request;
        string actionName = request.RouteValues["action"].ToString();
        string controllerName = request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString();
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization].ToString();

        if (token != "")
        {
            var t = handler.ReadJwtToken(token.Replace("Bearer ", "")) as JwtSecurityToken;
            
            var userId = t.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "userId").Value;

            if (dbContext.userAccessActions.Any(a => a.UserId == userId && a.ActionName == actionName && a.ControllName == controllerName))
           
                // اگر کاربر لاگین شده به اکشن مورد نظر دسترسی داشت.

                context.Succeed(requirement);
                else
                    //اگر دسترسی نداشت
                    context.Fail();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: then you should add exception handling to your code, e.g. `try { var t = handler.ReadJwtToken(... } {catch (System.ArgumentException e) { ... }.`

Comment: Please test it and write an answer, thank you

Comment: Please provide more related information about this question.